# Reproduce top tags for multiple users with Data Explorer

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, tag-score

I want to reproduce the top tags overview for multiple users with the Data Explorer:

[image]

In the following I simplify for two users. The required solution should be able to scale to 50+ users.

What I found is that I can filter for a user and get the tags per post.

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(
SELECT Tags FROM
Posts
WHERE Id IN 
(
SELECT
    ParentId
FROM
    Posts
WHERE
    OwnerUserId = 3502164
    )
) AS t
```

**What did I try?**

Well usually the way would be to go with Count(tags), but the tags don't seem to be text. I found that one could attempt to link the results to the "tag-table", but I just got a lot of messy SQL code.

**Sample desired Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** See [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1064945?CSVOfUsers=8538074%2C%201851712%2C%208603693).
It produces results like:

[image: query results]

---

Note:

1. "Top Tags" *Score* only counts answers, while *Posts* counts both Q&A.
2. "Top Tags" rank is computed by score. Ties are broken by post-count.
3. Community wiki posts ARE included in the post count, but only score earned before CW status counts.

---

To accept a CSV string of user ID's for input, use SEDE SQL like:

```sql
SELECT  u.Id  AS userId
FROM    Users u
WHERE   u.Id IN (
    SELECT  DISTINCT CAST (TRIM (value) AS INT)
    FROM    STRING_SPLIT (##CSVOfUsers:STRING##, ',')  -- Underscores not allowed in SEDE names
    WHERE   TRIM (value) != ''
)
```

Then get eligible posts like:

```
WITH targetUsers AS (
    SELECT  u.Id  AS UserId
    FROM    Users u
    WHERE   u.Id IN (
        SELECT  DISTINCT CAST (TRIM (value) AS INT)
        FROM    STRING_SPLIT (##CSVOfUsers:STRING##, ',')  -- Underscores not allowed in SEDE names
        WHERE   TRIM (value) != ''
    )
)
SELECT      tu.UserId
            -- "Top Tags" *Score* only counts answers...
            , Score   = (
                CASE    WHEN p.PostTypeId = 2  AND  p.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL
                        THEN p.Score     
                        ELSE 0     
                END
            )
            , parentQ = ( CASE WHEN p.PostTypeId = 2  THEN p.ParentId  ELSE p.Id  END )
            , postId  = p.Id
FROM        targetUsers tu
INNER JOIN  Posts p                 ON p.OwnerUserId = tu.UserId
WHERE       p.PostTypeId            IN (1, 2) -- Q&A only
```

Then the ranked tags per user:

```
rankedTagsPerUser AS (
    SELECT      ep.UserId
                , pt.TagId
                , tagScore = SUM (ep.Score)
                , numPosts = COUNT (ep.postId)
                , Rank = DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY    ep.UserId
                    ORDER BY        SUM (ep.Score) DESC,
                                    COUNT (ep.postId) DESC
                )
    FROM        eligiblePosts ep
    INNER JOIN  PostTags pt             ON pt.PostId = ep.parentQ
    GROUP BY    ep.UserId, pt.TagId
)
```

---

The next part is tricky because you want a pivot table, but we don't know the name or number of columns in advance.
That means dynamic SQL is required and a temp table helps a lot.

So for all that, see [**the final query on SEDE**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1064945?CSVOfUsers=8538074%2C%201851712%2C%208603693).

Answer (score 2):

The `Tags` field isn't really fit for analysis like this, and furthermore it's only filled for questions. You should really join with the `PostTags` and `Tags` table. I suspect you do like to experiment yourself a bit, so here is a little help in this regard: a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1064392/score-and-posts-per-tag?UserId=4751173) listing a single user's score and # of posts in each tag. It pretty much matches [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=profile):

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you for the fast Reply. You are right i dont expect someone to do the coding for me. Its a way better start than mine (+1). Do you have a hint how i can scale across multiple users 50, 100+?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would like to enter those IDs (maybe as comma-separated values), but you'd need to change both instances of `OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##` into `OwnerUserId IN (<something>)`, and add these OwnerUserIds to the respective `GROUP BY` clauses and the `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Then, you can probably do some magic with `PIVOT`, but that takes too much time for me to figure out right now.